# How can i use the carousel of bootstrap such that it doesn't change the height when user move from slide 1 to slide 2

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  background-color: #CAF7E3;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 15%;
}
.navbar{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-brand{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.nav-item{
  margin-right: 2rem;

}
#title{
  padding: 8% 15%;
  background-color: #F8EDED;
}
.slogun{
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.img-fruit{
  padding-left: 9%;
}
.fruit{
  width: 90%;
}
.carousel-inner{
padding: 8% 15%;
}
.unsplash{
object-fit: none;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Grocery Store</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 slogun">
              Not only an apple but fruits every day keeps the doctor away
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 img-fruit">
              <img class="fruit" src="photos/fruit.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="unsplash" src="photos/check.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is slide 2 I took the landscape photo from unsplash.com and used it here but since then when I move from slide 1 to slide 2 the carousel section height increases due to image and also the image doesn't in the width of the carousel-item (the image name in the html is check.png) how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give fixed height and width to the images as required by the carousel:

```
<img class="fruit" src="photos/fruit.png" alt="" height="50" width="200" >
```

(Height and Width are in Pixels.)

Comment: i am taking about check image in slide 2 under the class name unsplash

Comment: This same thing can be implemented with any image.                                                                                               <img class="unsplash" src="photos/check.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="200" >

Comment: And what to do so that it also become responsive so that it doesn't change Hight in mobile too

Comment: For that you should use JavaScript to scale the image according to the viewport hieght and width.